# Webdav on iis7.5 - always shows empty folder

Tags: web, iis, iis-7.5, webdav

I've followed all directions on configuring webdav on iis7.5 from this url:

> http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/350/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis-7/

The only difference is, I'm configuring it on a different website, not on the root website.

I can connect remotely (from my win7 desktop) but it always shows an empty folder. When connecting it doesn't request a login, but I've tried specifying the admin login and password, and still just a blank folder is shown.

Anyone have other pointers to try out for this?